# Can website framerate affect audio in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, frame-rate

If a website has an audio source - say from a media stream - does the website render framerate affect it? E.g. low frame rate leads to choppy audio. I was unsure if these are handled in separate threads in modern browsers (and if those threads could cannibalize resources from eachother).

Comment: That will depend on a lot of factors... Generally speaking, audio is processed on different threads (and even device) than the main realm, so is some of the rendering. Now depending on how is generated your audio or your rendering, it may have to sometimes come back on the main thread. Having it blocked may cause both the audio and the rendering to stop. If too many threads are being used (e.g lots of workers and tabs) then the audio thread may also suffer from that. All in all, your question would probably be a lot more interesting if you could narrow it down to a simple and clear use-case.

Comment: I am streaming audio over WebRTC and then doing an animation related to it (spectrum analyser)